# How rm * works in case of huge number of files in AIX (ksh)

Tags: ksh, aix, rm

Is there any limit of arguments that can be passed to rm command in AIX? I use ksh. I tried to run

```
rm *
```

in one catalog where is >500 000 (now) files but I received strange error. If I remember correctly it was something like "memory core dump". What does it mean? Can I suppose some files were removed? I don't know how many files were there before I executed this command.

I think shell was not able to collect all filenames and pass those to rm command so nothing was removed, but I really don't know. Can someone advise me how it works?

Comment: When you do not have subdirs and you are sure you are in the correct dir, you can remove the files using   
find . -exec rm -f {} \;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long an argument list is allowed to be is defined by `ARG_MAX` which you can query using `getconf`, e.g.:

```
$ uname -o
GNU/Linux

$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

This is not a limit set by the shell but by the underlying system call(s) involved.

Comment: Thanks, I have one milion arguments. Can I suppose that one milion files were removed and then I got error? Shouldn't be error "Too many arguments"? Why memory core dump?

Comment: That's hard for me to say because - as you say - you should rather get an error à la *"Too many arguments"* instead of a core dump. Can you try to reproduce this with `/bin/echo *` in the same directory (don't use the builtin `echo` which is not subject to `ARG_MAX`, you have to use the external) and see what happens?

Comment: @nosbor `ARG_MAX` is not a limit on the number of arguments, but the maximum size, in bytes, of the *buffer* used to pass the environment *and* the entire argument list through the `exec()` system call.

Comment: ... and because it's not the count but the buffersize in bytes the error should be *"argument list too long"*, shouldn't have copy'n'pasted that.

Comment: Ok, so I can conclude that nothing was removed. Thanks a lot guys!